# How to alter column to VARCHAR type with length L where L is based on the column aggregation like MAX(LENGTH(column)), PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, varchar, alter, correlated-subquery

I am trying to alter column named `names` type from text to VARCHAR with length L. Where L is the maximum length of the `names`. I am trying with inner/sub-query as follows:

Is this even possible? Any alternative to do this in a single query?

```
ALTER TABLE friends
ALTER COLUMN names TYPE VARCHAR(
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(names))
    FROM friends
)
```

I get the following error in PgAdmin4 SQL console:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 3:  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(card_number))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equivalent of `VARCHAR(MAX)` on Postgres, which can be achieved by simply using `VARCHAR` alone with no size:

```sql
ALTER TABLE friends ALTER COLUMN names TYPE VARCHAR;
```

Note that with `VARCHAR` any given string will only use storage for that string alone, with no padding (unlike `CHAR`).

Or, we could use the `TEXT` type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE friends ALTER COLUMN names TYPE TEXT;
```

Comment: It would be better to use the equivalent `text` as it is the preferred string data type and will make type resolution problems less likely.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be better off using [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).
Answering the question: you can't use anything but integer constants in that context, so to achieve that "in a single query", you'll need dynamic SQL.

```
create table a(b varchar(60));
insert into a values ('123456789'),('12345');

select data_type,character_maximum_length 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='a' and table_schema='public' and column_name='b';
```

| data_type | character_maximum_length |
| --- | --- |
| character varying | 60 |

```
do $f$
declare new_len_limit int;
begin
select max(length(b)) from a into new_len_limit;
execute format('alter table a alter column b type varchar(%s)',new_len_limit);
end $f$ language plpgsql;

select data_type,character_maximum_length 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='a' and table_schema='public' and column_name='b';
```

| data_type | character_maximum_length |
| --- | --- |
| character varying | 9 |

```
alter table a alter column b type varchar(select 5);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
> LINE 1: alter table a alter column b type varchar(select 5);
>                                                   ^
> ```

```
create function max_b_len() returns int language sql as 'select 5';
alter table a alter column b type varchar(max_b_len());
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "max_b_len"
> LINE 1: alter table a alter column b type varchar(max_b_len());
>                                                   ^
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JldMs-9t)